# some question about L1 convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve exercise in chung's a course in probability theory.

Question is

If $X_n \downarrow X a.s.$, each $X_n$ is integrable and $inf_n E(X_n) > -\infty$, then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$.

I couldn't prove above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First apply Monotone Convergence Theorem to $(X_1-X_n)$ to show that $EX_n \to EX$. Then note that $E|X_n -X|=EX_n -EX \to 0$.